# View returning null on tablet but working fine on phone

Tags: java, android, tablet

I've currently got the following;

```
setupHideKeyboard( findViewById( R.id.login_layout ), this );
public void setupHideKeyboard( final View view, final Activity activity ) {

    if ( !( view instanceof EditText ) ) {

        view.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener() {
        // crashes on the above line

            public boolean onTouch( View v, MotionEvent event ) {

                hideSoftKeyboard( activity );
                view.setFocusableInTouchMode( true );
                view.requestFocus();
                return false;
            }

        });
    }

    if ( view instanceof ViewGroup ) {

        for ( int childView = 0; childView < ( ( ViewGroup) view ).getChildCount(); childView++ ) {

            View innerView = ( ( ViewGroup ) view ).getChildAt( childView );
            setupHideKeyboard( innerView, activity );
        }
    }
```

that is being used to set a on touch listener to hide the keyboard when a edittext is not pressed, this WORKS FINE on my HTC One M7, but crashes on my Samsung Galaxy Tab S 10.5.

The view for some reason is null on the tab s but fine on the m7.
Any obvious idea why?

It's like it can't find the `R.id.login_layout` do large xml have a different name to smaller ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is a same layout file in your layout and layout-large/layout-xlarge folder. But login_layout is defined only in the layout folder file. So since the tablet would take the xml from layout-large/layout-xlarge, there is no problem with inflation, but it is not able to get the login_layout view from that layout file. Hence you are getting a crash.

Comment: cheers wasn't quite the issue, but was along the right lines. I forgot I named the linear layout on the normal layout and not on the large one :)